# Show error message instead of exception

Tags: java, error-handling

I'm trying to make a program that gets a number from the user and checks the number is a prime number or not. I was thinking about the error handling. When the user enters a string the program should give an error message instead of an exception. I tried many methods but couldn't be successful. Could you guys help me with that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumber {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputNum;
    int remainingNum;
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

    inputNum = input.nextInt();

    if(inputNum < 0){      
      System.out.println("Please enter a possitive number.");      
    }

    for(int i = 2; i<=inputNum; i++) {

      remainingNum = inputNum % i;

      if(remainingNum == 0){
        System.out.println("This number is not a prime number.");
        break;
      }
      if(remainingNum == 1){
        System.out.println("This is a prime number!");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: exception handling is what you meant is it and what did you try

Comment: Please read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions. What you call a "compiler error" is an exception.

Comment: what is the exception you are getting anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If user enters a non-integer input, this line

```
inputNum = input.nextInt();
```

will throw an exception (an `InputMismatchException`). The way Java *handles exceptions* is through a `try-catch` block:

```
try {
    inputNum = input.nextInt();
    // ... do domething with inputNum ...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
}
```

**Note:** If you want to know more about exceptions (and you must) you can read [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html).

Answer (score 0):

just put it in try-catch and then print your message when exception occurs mean in the catch clause..its simple thing

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the input first and if it is a number check for prime and if it is invalid prompt user for another input until he enter a valid one, try this.

```
          String inputString;
            boolean isValid = false;

            while(isValid == false){
            //sysout for input 
            inputString = input.nextLine(); 

            if(inputString.matches("[0-9]+")){

                // check for prime
                isValid = true;

            }else{

           //printin error
               }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to every one especially to Christian. Here is the latest code.

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumber {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {






    try {
        Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNum;
        int remainingNum;
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

        inputNum = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = 2; i<=inputNum; i++) {

            remainingNum = inputNum % i;



            if(remainingNum == 0){
                System.out.println("This number is not a prime number.");
                break;


            }


            if(remainingNum == 1){
                System.out.println("This is a prime number!");
                break;
            }


        }


    } 
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }









}



}
```